# Replacing text based on another cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, replace

I have an employee table with their operation and attendance status. I would like to replace their operation with absent where its listed Sick,Vacation,leave. I had tried some thing similar like in the code below but I lost the code that worked but it only worked a specific cell and not the whole range. I would like a vba code that will replace column A with absent if a certain condition is met. I do know how to do it manually by applying a filter but I would appreciate it if someone can help me with a vba loop where it checks for value in Paycode column and replace their opertion.

Thanks

```
  Sub IF_OR_Test()
    For Each Cell In Range("B2:B999")
        If Range("B2").Value = "Sick" Then
       Range("A2").Value = "Absent"
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Sample Data:
[image: Employee Table]

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Sub IF_OR_Test()
dim cl as range
    For Each cl In Range("B2:B999")
        If cl.Value = "Sick" Then
       cl.offset(0,-1).Value = "Absent"
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```